# Rails plugin development documentation and resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Are there any resources or documentation for developing Rails plugins?
I'm using other plugins as examples, but it's hard to know if I'm doing something wrong, or if there's another way to do something. All I can find are old blog posts. I haven't found any documentation on how to develop plugins and what functionality/hooks are available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this very good list:

- [HOWTO: Make A Rails Plugin From Scratch](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=682)
- [Rails Plugin Tutorial](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/18/rails-plugin-tutorial/)
- [Demystifying Rails Plugin Development](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7976548/Demystifying-Rails-Plugin-Development)
- [How to write a Rails Plugin (for controllers)](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/06/how-to-write-a-rails-plugin-for-controllers/?doing_wp_cron)
- [The Basics of Creating Rails Plugins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html)
- [Build Your Own Rails Plugin Platform with Desert](http://pivotallabs.com/users/brian/blog/articles/459-build-your-own-rails-plugin-platform-with-desert)
- [Extending Rails: Understanding and Building Plugins](http://en.oreilly.com/oscon2008/public/schedule/detail/2321)
- [Screencast: How to develop Plugins in Rails - The Basics](http://www.bestechvideos.com/2008/06/25/ruby-plus-13-how-to-develop-plugins-in-rails-the-basics)(View all the other 4 parts)

Also, to improve your knowleadge, I'm going to suggest some resources to learn about Gem development:

- [Creating Your Own Gem](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/5)
- [Creating a gem under Ruby](http://blogs.cocoondev.org/crafterm/archives/004653.html)
- [Creating a RubyGem Package](http://www.5dollarwhitebox.org/drupal/creating_a_rubygem_package)

In this tutorials and How-Tos, you will learn very good(and much) about this very nice and useful world **;)**