# What's a good place for modules in a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm adding some non-trivial functionality in my rails application and it needs to be in a module and not one of the auto generated models.  I'd like a few suggestions on where the file containing the module should go (currently I've added a 'code' directory on the same level as 'models' and 'views' - but I don't know that that's a strong choice).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most people add this type of code in `lib`

Answer (score 3):

If it's related to the controller/view layer, consider putting the functionality in a [helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html). If not, lib is a good general storage directory for util classes and the like. If at all possible, think about making extra code like this a [plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814136/rails-plugin-development-documentation-and-resources), as it helps keep the codebase clean and reusable functionality available to other projects.